# Degrees of freedom of wrist

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Why does a wrist have 3 degrees of freedom? The image below illustrates them but pronation can be done even without the wrist present so I don't understand why it is considered to be a degree of freedom of the wrist. During pronation the whole wrist itself is moving.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does a wrist have 3 degrees of freedom?

Is the premise of the question correct? Consider a simple online search for `wrist "two degrees of freedom"`:

- "The articular complex of the wrist has basically **two degrees of freedom**. When these are compounded with pronation and supination, i.e. rotation of the forearm around its long axis, the hand can be oriented at any angle to grasp or hold an object." Kapandji, *The Physiology of the Joints*, vol. 1, p. 130, [full text](https://archive.org/stream/382169905kapandjithephysiologyofthejointsvolume1theupperlimb/382169905-Kapandji-The-Physiology-of-the-Joints-Volume-1-The-Upper-Limb_djvu.txt).
- "The wrist movements are limited to **two degrees of freedom**: flexion–extension and ulnar–radial deviation. The apparent axial rotation of the palm—called pronation and supination—occurs at the proximal and DRUJs, with the hand moving with the radius, not separately from it." ([Source](https://orthofixar.com/special-test/hand-wrist-movements/).)
- "The wrist has **two degrees of freedom**, that is, flexion and extension and ulnar and radial deviation." ([Source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3193629/).)
- "...the carpus essentially moves with **only two degrees of freedom**-pitch (flexion/extension) and yaw (radial deviation/ulnar deviation)-while largely preventing roll (pronation/supination)." ([Source](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30659546/).)
- "The wrist has **two degrees of freedom**: pitch (flexion/extension) and yaw (radial and ulnar deviation).
  All other movements are resisted, including rotation (prono-supination)" ([Source](https://www.woc.com.au/pdf/sandow-the-wrist-explained-2020.pdf).)
- "The wrist has **two degrees of freedom** which must be measured. In addition the wrist has several small motions which make it difficult to transduce the major wrist motions." ([Source](http://www.oandplibrary.org/al/1955_02_022.asp).)
- "**No significant torsion occurs.**" ([Source](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19930002769/downloads/19930002769.pdf).)

So, no, I don't buy the premise of the question. This is a subjective matter of biomedical/biomechanics terminology/convention. Some authors model the wrist joint as having only two primary degrees of freedom as a joint, with any pronation at all subsumed into rotation around the longitudinal axis of the forearm. Others broadly include pronation motion of the entire wrist as a degree of freedom of the lower arm associated with wrist revolution, or include pronation measured under certain test conditions.*

<sup>*[Example](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/3968403/): "Our electrogoniometer was designed with the capability of measuring rotation as well as flexion/extension
and radioulnar deviation. However, it was not felt that
the goniometer was accurate for rotation unless it was
affixed directly to the bone with Steinmann pins. The
one subject who was tested with the goniometer affixed
to the bone revealed that for each task performed, wrist
rotation ranged from 2.2° to 11.8° with an average of
6.9°. We feel that this confirms that the wrist joint has
not two but three degrees of freedom."</sup>